# I am trying to write a Junit Test for this method, for context I have included a current test I have

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to test the getOrGenerateID() method below in the generateClass class. I am struggling with writing a test that will test the logic of the method. I believe my current test as it is does not ensure coverage of all logic in the method

```
public class GenerateId {
    static final Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();

    public static String getOrGenerateID() {
        if (map.containsKey("TestMapKey")) {   //check if map has a key
            return map.get("TestMapKey");     // return the value for the key
        }
        else {
            String newUId = "newID";
            map.put("TestMapKey", newUId);
            return newUId;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Unit test I have written so far:**

```
public void getOrGenerateIDTest() {
    map.put("TestMapKey", "TestMapValue");
    String newID = getOrGenerateID();
    Assertions.assertTrue(map.containsKey("TestMapKey"));
    Assertions.assertEquals("TestMapValue", map.get("TestMapKey");
}
```

Comment: Your test makes absolutely no sense, you're asserting on a map object that has _no connection at all_ to the code you're supposed to be testing. I'd expect to see some assertion on `newID`, the value actually returned by the method.

Comment: Your method is unnecessarily complex. Just `return "newID";` will do the same, no need for the map.

Comment: Please add  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). Also clarify what the *public observable behavior* of your code under test really is.